# What is the determinant of an exact triangle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have an exact sequence of coherent sheaves $$E_\bullet:\,\,\,0\to E_1\to E_2\to E_3\to 0$$ on a smooth projective variety $X$. Suppose we have an equivalence $F:D^b(X)\to D^b(Y)$. Then in particular we have an exact triangle $$F(E_\bullet):\,\,\,F(E_1)\to F(E_2)\to F(E_3)\to F(E_1)[1].$$ 
In the $K$-theory of any triangulated category we have $$[B]=[A]+[C]$$ for any exact triangle $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$. Now, since the determinant of bounded complexes is supposed to behave well with respect to $K$-theory, I am led to think that one must have $$\det F(E_2)=\det F(E_1)\otimes \det F(E_3),$$ as a reminiscence of the classical $$\det E_2=\det E_1\otimes \det E_3.$$ But I cannot find a reference for this fact. Is it true? Do you know a reference?

Thanks a lot for any help!